# Is there a way to use awesome_print gem for each project's rails console without adding into Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to use awesome_print for each project `rails console`, I tried with adding these lines into `~./irbrc` file but still it is not working.

`$LOAD_PATH.unshift
    '/Users/vijay/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/awesome_print-1.8.0/lib/'
    require 'awesome_print'
    AwesomePrint.irb!`

Comment: This might help you https://youtu.be/Jkq0r4gmGW0

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you verify the .irbrc is working? `Puts 'Hi'` and see if you're going to see the output on initialization, if it's working, then verify the next step.
2. Can you verify that the directory exists? and when you use rails c, does it 
   print any message on initialization? Usually, if there's a problem with your .irbrc it will raise a warning before it initializes, 
   for example: `cannot load such file -- awesome_print`.

Are you using rbenv? if you're using rvm for example, you might find it in: '/Users/vijay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/awesome_print-1.8.0/lib''

Comment: file .irbrc is working fine and also it is not giving any error as directory exists and I am using rbenv.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer for rbenv set-up

1. nano ~/.irbrc
2. copy below code into irbrc file

   begin
       $LOAD_PATH << '/home/ajit/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/awesome_print-1.8.0/lib/'
       require 'awesome_print'
       AwesomePrint.irb!
       puts "awesome_print gem installed, enjoy :)"

   rescue Loaderror => err
       puts "no awesome_print :("
   end